# why is the mongodb oplog is idempotent? Even for insert operation?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I am learning the replica set function of mongodb and when i read this article:
[replica set oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)

it said:

> Each operation in the oplog is idempotent. That is, oplog operations produce the same results whether applied once or multiple times to the target dataset.

What does it mean? An insert or delete operation surely produce different result applying once than twice.

So maybe i am wrong or somebody explain it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An insert or delete operation surely produce different result applying once than twice.

You can't delete things twice. If you were to apply the same delete operation again, it would be a no-op.

As for the insert: it's been a while since I looked at oplog, but I'm quite sure that replicated insert operation includes value for `_id`. And so it too won't insert a second copy of a document (because `_id` must be unique)

Comment: i think you are right; i will check the oplog for some detail.